# Java JFrame setImageIcon image from URL not working

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

So by default I have no image placed on the window frame and I am looking to add an image to be placed on the corner of the frame when my app runs. I've browsed the forums and saw a bunch of solutions which didn't help me at all. My program runs without errors but the image doesn't show up.. However when the program is ran in linux the main nav-bar (on top) does set the image when I focus on my application, this does not occur in MacOS though.

My Code:

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        Image image = null;
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://www.multivutech.com/images/logo1.png");
            image = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Malformed URL");
        } catch (IOException iox) {
            System.out.println("Can not load file");
        }
        
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        panel.add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Hello World Frame!");
        frame.setIconImage(image);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(354, 279);
```

Comment: Windows works fine, but bad .png as Logo.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working on a mac is that the Frame does not display icons.

If you add this, then you can change the icon displayed in the Dock:

```
Taskbar.getTaskbar().setIconImage(image);
```

Here is an example based on your code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JFrameImageIconDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Hello World Frame!");
        frame.setSize(354, 279);

        URL url = new URL("https://www.multivutech.com/images/logo1.png");
        Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
        Taskbar.getTaskbar().setIconImage(image);
        frame.setIconImage(image);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Do you know if the ubuntu frame displays icons? because it doesn't show it there either but it does show it on the dock so I assume the .png is ok.

Comment: I don't have an Ubuntu installation to test it on, but maybe this will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979754/jframe-icon-not-displaying-in-ubuntu-12-04